# how to hide Outlet in Xcode and save it from never appearing again?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to hide a outlet that is also a button after the action is made, then I need it to be saved so it doesn't appear again.

Ive used in the cation

```
- (IBAction)giveheart:(id)sender {
[_heartM setHidden:YES];

 nLife = [lblLife.text intValue]+1;
[savedStock setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:nLife] forKey:@"life"];
[savedStock writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
}
```

Now I need to save it to not appear again even when the app is turned off and on again.

How is that done, and what should I do?

Comment: What's `savedStock`? Can you not just save it to `NSUserDefaults`? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: '[(UIView*)sender setHidden:YES]' ?

Comment: NSUserDefault is best way, you just update/save state in NSUserDefault and every time check with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the state in the  NSUserDefaults when button pressed.

```
 - (IBAction)giveheart:(id)sender {
 //Save the state in NSUserDefaults here
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:@"Yes" forKey:@"hide"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
[_heartM setHidden:YES];

 nLife = [lblLife.text intValue]+1;
[savedStock setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:nLife] forKey:@"life"];
[savedStock writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
}
```

in ViewDidLoad method of the viewcontroller

```
NSString *status = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"hide"];
if(status != nil && [status isEqualToString:@"Yes"] )
[_heartM setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: This will not work and will throw an error, can you see your mistake? **EDIT** Actually you have more then one mistake so -1 until they are corrected, I will remove when they have been corrected

Comment: As promised I have removed my -1

Answer (score 1):

You can save the state of the button to NSUserDefaults as follows.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:_heartM.isHidden] forKey:@"buttonState"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

When you view is loaded, you can get the status of button from the defaults

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *boolNum = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"buttonState"];
if(boolNum) {
    _heartM.hidden = [boolNum boolValue];
}
```

Comment: hey, it worked, but can i use forkey@"hint" because that seems to work too?

Comment: error at [_heartM.hidden = [boolNum boolValue]; for expected identifier

Comment: This is incorrect as well for the same reasons as `Gyanendra Singh` answer.

Comment: its just that one identifier issue, Cant seem to correct it!

Comment: @jumpper correct `[_heartM.hidden = [boolNum boolValue];` by doing one of two options either `[_heartM setHidden:[boolNum boolValue]];` or `_heartM.hidden = [boolNum boolValue];`. Note the extra `[` at the beginning.

Comment: @jumpper.. You can use any key.. it is always good to use something sensible.. And also make sure you are using the same key while setting and reading the object from defaults..